# Using custom filter in angular don't work with date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use angular filter to show dates in an special format, but, when I use this basic code I'm get this error:
**angular.js:12221 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myFilterFilterProvider...**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('appController', function ($scope) {
  var d = new Date();
  $scope.days = [
    {
      name: 'A string date',
      value: d
    }
  ];
})

.filter('dateFilter', function() {
   return function(value) {
      return value;
    }
})
```

Then, I put this code in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular filter</title>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="day in days">
      <span>{{day.name}}</span>
      <p>{{day.value | myFilter }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
angular.js:12221 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myFilterFilterProvider <- myFilterFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/unpr?p0=myFilterFilterProvider%20%3C-%20myFilterFilter
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4238
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4385)
    at angular.js:4243
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4385)
    at angular.js:17951
    at isStateless (angular.js:12845)
    at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (angular.js:12902)
    at angular.js:12856
    at forEach (angular.js:336)
```

Comment: name of yur filter is dateFilter then why u used myFilter in html

Answer (score 0):

use dateFilter instead of myFilter in HTML

```
<p>{{day.value | dateFilter }}</p>
```

error is about injector of myFilter.
you have not declared myFilter anywhere.  So you are getting the error regarding filter